# Running tomcat 8.5 on digital ocean droplet ubuntu 18.10

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

I am trying to get tomcat 8.5 to run in an ubuntu 18.10 droplet on digital ocean. There are various tutorials on installing and running tomcat as a service on the web. Most of them are very similar. I have followed this tutorial from digital ocean exactly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804

For some reason no matter what...tomcat never opens port 8080. I ran the command for firewall to allow 8080. I also modified the tomcat service script to use root instead of tomcat user. Just to make sure it wasnt user permissions. The same thing happens.... nothing. I get no errors in the logs and the service status as all SUCCESS. So, I have no trace of where to troubleshoot to find the error. Contacted support for digital ocean and they were not helpful.

Anyone have any ideas??

Jim

Comment: As a side question, what are you planning on running inside of Tomcat? If you're starting a new project, most Java tools these days support and encourage embedded containers instead of dealing with container headaches.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I need to explore more options out there cuz I am too old school. :( I am trying to learn more about the different tools.

Comment: With Boot (and I believe Dropwizard, maybe Micronaut) it's as simple as having a JVM installed and running `java -jar myapp.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching from their 18.10 image to 18.04 and i got it to work with the howto. There must be something different in 18.10.